# Expandable list not working as intended

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a program that grabs a list and adds a class to parts of the list that contains sub lists under it. The problem I am having is that the list gets the classes added properly, but when I try to add an onclick event it doesn't work as expected. The onclick works but only for the last occurrence of the found list item. so clicking on any of the blue words to expand or reduce will cause the last list to change only.

I think it has to do with not having an id to make it unique so the last list item created is the one effected by the on click event.

I would like to accomplish this without jquery or editing the HTML. A way I can see this working is by making an ID but is there a way I can do this without that approach?

https://jsfiddle.net/ooa72wLm/

```
if(innerlist.querySelectorAll('li').length > 0){
    tx.innerHTML = tx.innerHTML + ' -';
    innerlist.parentElement.querySelector('div').className = 'collapse';
    innerlist.parentElement.querySelector('div').addEventListener("click", function(){
        if(tx.innerHTML.substr(tx.innerHTML.indexOf(' ')+1) === '-'){
            tx.innerHTML = tx.innerHTML.substr(0,tx.innerHTML.indexOf(' ')) +' +';
          innerlist.className = 'hide';
          innerlist.removeClassName = 'view';
        }
        else{
            tx.innerHTML = tx.innerHTML.substr(0,tx.innerHTML.indexOf(' ')) +' -';
          innerlist.className = 'view';
          innerlist.removeClassName = 'hide';
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't know your entire code but usually the solution is to add only one event to the parent element and delegate it.

Now, your error is coming from the fact that you do for loop:

    for(var i = 1; i < list.length; i++){

and then assign this variable:

    var innerlist = list[i];

In JS you don't have block scope so the last assignment to this variable happens on the last iteration of the loop -> you basically hard code the last item inside there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the scope of 2 variables you're declaring:

```
var innerlist = list[i];
var tx = innerlist.parentElement.querySelector('div');
```

These are declared within a for loop, however `var` is not block scoped. This means that for each iteration of the loop, the values are reassigned. When the click listener function is fired, the values have therefore changed.

If you're able to use ES6 features, I would recommend using `let` instead of `var`, as this is block scoped.

Here is an updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ooa72wLm/1/